# LogRocket CLI: unable to create a release when uploading source maps

Tags: source-maps, logrocket

Following the steps here, I'm trying to upload source maps to LogRocket using their CLI, but this step:

```
logrocket release 0.1.50 --apikey="secret"
```

...results in:

```
Creating release: 0.1.50 ...
Could not create release: 0.1.50
500 Internal Server Error
Could not complete request
```

I've tried different combination of releases (e.g. v50, blahblah, etc), and they all result in the same error.

I don't think the API key is the problem, as I sent an invalid API key and the response was `403 Forbidden` instead.

Anyone know how to diagnose this problem? I've also asked on their GitHub page: https://github.com/LogRocket/logrocket-cli/issues/16

Answer (score 1):

One thing to try is passing the release as a number, e.g.

```
logrocket release 1.0 --apikey="secret"
```

Strings such as 0.8.4 will also work but need to be quoted, e.g.

```
logrocket release "0.8.4" --apikey="secret"
```